# Kinect v2 on Windows 7

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, openkinect

So I finally got my two Kinect v2's in the mail, and was looking forward to get some raw data from them and see how much they interfere with each other.  I went to go download the SDK, and for some reason I had never noticed the Windows 8 requirements... As in Windows 7 isn't supported.

This feels pretty bogus and unnecessary, but fine I can't do anything about that.  Before I waste some money to upgrade my machine to an OS that I really don't want, is there any way to get the Kinect v2s to talk to a Windows 7 machine (or maybe even Ubuntu)?  I don't need any of the fancy skeletal detection or anything; I just want raw `xyz-rgb` data.  I was reading about OpenNI (and their new Apple overlords), and I was hoping that by some miracle their last open source distributions would be forwards compatible with the Kinect v2s?

**TL;DR:** Are there any free SDKs that can interface with a Kinect v2 on Windows 7-64bit?

Comment: I'd like to know how this worked out for you. We're making a small academic project with skeleton tracking using Kinect V2, and our industrial partner asked us if it was possible to run it on Windows 7. I've managed to run openkinect2 on Ubuntu before, but it seems I can't get skeleton tracking...

Comment: @BirgerSkogengPedersen We ended up using libfreenect2 with Ubuntu 16.  The library is purely to help you interface with a Kinectv2.  If you want to get the skeletal tracking code you're probably going to need the actual Kinect SDK, with all of its Windows requirements.  If you plan to roll out your own skeletal tracking code, libfreenect2 was a bit shaky at first works pretty well in Ubuntu with its more recent release tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

look at [libfreenect2](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2)

It looks like its not ready yet but there are people working on it. So you might want help them along.

**Update 2014-10-28**

The Project is live and kicking and works fine

Comment: I did see that, but I was a bit dubious when I read "retrieves so far unknown data blobs from the sensor (probably color-to-IR registration data and such)".  It sounds like it is still very young, although it is a very noble effort.  I will switch to it once it matures, but I have too many projects to devote time to it.  Time to bite the bullet and pay Microsoft more money...

Comment: I don't get this. It's an alternative for the Win 8 limited SDK v2, but the installation instructions say to install SDK v2 first....

Answer (score 0):

Just dropping by to say that I successfully 'installed' the Kinect 2 SDK to windows 7 and it is being recognized by driver4vr.
I'm not precisely sure which files where required so I'll just post my process.

1. Install VirtualBox (and enable CPU virtualization in bios to support 64bit OS)
2. Install win 8.1 x64 in VirtualBox
3. Monitor the VirtualBox c-drive for changes (I used spy-the-spy)
4. Download and install the Kinect 2 SDK in VirtualBox
5. Check spy-the-spy for all files added, and copy them to your Windows 7 OS on the same location. (It also installs some VC redistributables, so skip the files already there)
6. Reboot windows 7 and enjoy Kinect 2.0 on the final decent MS OS.

Comment: Welcome to [so].Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Use `code blocking` for code and log and error texts and **bold** and *italics* to highlight things

Answer (score -1):

The Windows 8 is MINIMUM requirement to developing kinect v2
you do not need use Skeleton(kinect V1) or Body(Kinect V2) to track body or skeleton .
you need use to MultiFrameSource Class